# How to use switch case in Mustache template?

Tags: php, switch-statement, mustache

I'm using Mustache template in Core PHP to turn PHP pages to template. Now I want to use switch case in template like:

```
<?php
    switch ($gift_card['FlagStatus']) {
        case 'P': 
            echo "Pending";
            break;
        case 'A':
            echo "Active";
            break;
        case 'I':
            echo "Inactive";
            break;
    }
```

?>

what should be its similar Mustache translation? 
thanks in advance

Comment: Erm, isn't Mustache **logic-less** template engine and you're trying to do exactly that, implement logic? The actual Mustache "translation" would be exactly the same thing you wrote, except echoing you'd set variables to values you're echoing.

Comment: @N.B. Exactly but I want to check conditions specifically. How can I do this job?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're aiming at.. what conditions? You already have switch/case - those are your conditions. Instead of echoing active/inactive/pending - you have to set a Mustache variable to a value. That's it. I don't see where the issue is, Mustache has everything documented and it's pretty easy to grasp, are you looking in how to use it or what? You're not being very clear.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to do more than just output a single value from the switch statement, the simplest workaround is to create a series of booleans, one for each state: `isPending`, `isInactive`, `isActive` etc and then use separate sections for each eventuality:

```
{{#isPending}}
Your gift card is pending. It will be activated on {{activationDate}}.
{{/isPending}}
{{#isActive}}
Your gift card is active. Its balance is ${{balance}}.
{{/isActive}}
{{#isInactive}}
Your gift card is inactive. Go <a href="/active/{{cardId}}">here</a> to reactivate it.
{{/isInactive}}
```

Answer (score 3):

The switch statement would go in the php, for example:

### In the php

```
$card_status = null;
switch ($gift_card['FlagStatus']) {
        case 'P': 
            $card_status = "Pending";
            break;
        case 'A':
            $card_status =  "Active";
            break;
        case 'I':
            $card_status = "Inactive";
            break;
    }

render_template('giftcard_stuff', array('card_status'=>$card_status);
```

### In the template

```
<div>The status of this gift card is: {{card_status}}</div>
```

Things get more tricky when you're trying to do things like put flags like that into a dropdown, in which case you'd have to write out the array in advance, like:

```
$status_dropdown = [
    ['flag_display'=>'Pending', 'flag'=>'P'],
    ['flag_display'=>'Active', 'flag'=>'A'],
    ['flag_display'=>'Inactive', 'flag'=>'I'],
];
```